# numpy 2d and 1d addition flat

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

While using the example from NumPy Book while starting out with NumPy I noted an example:

```
a = zeros((4, 5))
b = ones(6)
add(b, b, a[1:3, 0:3].flat)
print(a)
```

returns

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
       [2, 2, 2, 0, 0]
       [2, 2, 2, 0, 0]
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

However, when I try this code, it results in the following error:

> add(b, b, a[1:3, 0:3].flat)
>
> TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType"

Could anyone please shed some light on this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 2 arguments for `numpy.add` they are taken as the two operands that are `added`. If you give 3 arguments the first two are the ones that are added and the third one is the `result`. Well actually not the result but the array where the result should be saved in.

So you added `b` with `b` and wanted to store it in `a[1:3, 0:3].flat`.

Let's just try to `np.add(b, b)` which gives

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((4, 5))
b = np.ones(6)
np.add(b, b)
# returns array([ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.])
```

So now I tried `a[1:3, 0:3].flat` which returns `<numpy.flatiter at 0x22204e80c10>`. This means that it returns an `iterator` so it's no array. But we don't need an iterator we want an array. There is a method called `ravel()`. So trying `a[1:3, 0:3].ravel()` returns:

```
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

so we have an array. Especially the array is also usable for storing the result (same shape!). So I tried:

```
np.add(b, b, a[1:3, 0:3].ravel())
# array([ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.])
```

But let's see if `a` has changed:

```
a
#array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

So `a` hasn't changed. That's because `ravel()` only returns a view (assignment would propagate to the unravelled array) if possible otherwise it returns a copy. And saving the result in a copy is rather pointless because the whole point of the `out` parameter is that the operation is done in-place. I'm only guessing why a copy is made but I think it's because we take a portion out of a bigger array where the portion is not contiguous in the memory.

So I would propose that you don't use the `out` parameter in this case but use the return of the `np.add` and store it inside the specified region in `a`:

```
a[1:3, 0:3] = np.add(b, b).reshape(2,3) # You need to reshape here!
a
#array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  0.],
#       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  0.],
#       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Also `a[1:3, 0:3].flat = np.add(b, b)` works.

I think the book is either outdated and it worked with an older `numpy` version or it never worked at all and it was a mistake in the book.

Comment: Python Ver - 3.5, NumPy - 1.10.4. The book I was referring to was Guide to NumPy by Travis E. Oliphant, 2006. Maybe this is because of the conflict in versions of Python as well. Regardless, thank you for such a detailed answer. Very helpful!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, that's exactly the versions I'm using and I'm convinced that is a bug (or something that was deprecated between 2006 and now) with numpy because ``a[1:3, 0:3].flat = np.add(b, b)`` works too. And this should be equivalent to your ``np.add(b, b, a[1:3, 0:3].flat)``.

Comment: `a[...].flat=np.add(b,b)` works.  `flat` doc shows this assignment use.  Evidently something changed to disable its use as a `ufunc` `out` argument.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too and included it in the answer. I've also raised an issue on numpy: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7244. Maybe they know why it's not working.

Comment: Thanks @MSeifert. While replacing the array values by assigning np.add(b, b) works, but it only replaces the values inside the array, but does not actually add the value that is inside it. One can reference the values to another array as "k = a[1:3, 0:3].flat; a[1:3, 0:3].flat = add(b*2, k)", but it would be great if the module could be "fixed".

Comment: Yes it will always only replace the values. That's the intended behaviour in ``a[...].flat=np.add(b,b)`` as well as in ``np.add(b, b, a[...].flat)``, because you specified it as placeholder for the result of the ``np.add``. If you want to include ``a[...].flat`` in the calculation you need to specify it as one of the operators or make the operation ``in-place``: ``a[...] += np.add(b, b)`` (that will not work without reshaping though).

Comment: You can delete reference to my answer if you'd like. There is more to this problem than I originally thought. Isn't there two bugs? For one it should treat and modify the flat array properly and for two it shouldn't return the array when it modifies it in-place (imo).

Comment: The [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.add.html) state that there is always a return. I was a bit surprised at that too (why need a result if the output is specified) but that maybe has a reason, even if it's just consistency. I need to edit the answer a bit to take that into account, I'll do that later.

Comment: I've been mistaken about ``ravel()`` and ``reshape()``. I assumed these would always return a ``view`` and not a ``copy`` of the array. But in this case they both return a copy and storing the result in a copy is rather useless. I've updated the answer.